# ReasonML sample web server with a db

Tags: database, webserver, reason

I've been taking a look at ReasonML (https://reasonml.github.io/) and in general, as a 'loyal' ;) functional programmer, I like the idea. However, I believe there's a missing part in my reasoning about the project.

In particular I'm a bit confused if it comes what to search for. For example, I'd like to build a simple web server. Shall I use JS-related libraries (express, ...), OCaml technologies, or maybe yet something else ?

What I'm actually missing is a step-by-step guide that presents a way to build a full basic application (in this case: let's say a simple web server with db connection).

Last thing - forgive me imprecise language. As I said: I'm pretty sure there's a gap in my reasoning about ReasonML and I'd like to fill it ;).

Comment: Not directly answer your question but you can listen to this podcast https://reason.town/server-side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write portable code, you should use the *OCaml technologies*, so  `Array.length` (from OCaml core) instead of `Js.Array.length` (Bucklescript JS wrapper).

If you do not care about native code, but just want to target JS (node/browser), then you can use the FFI and leverage your existing knowledge of JS libraries.

IMHO, this FFI is one of the nicer things of reasonML. The resulting code is small and you can inspect the `.bs.js` files to see what it's doing.

But as said, you lose the ability to generate native code this way.

---

Here is an example,

> https://github.com/wires/reason-ffi

Say I don't have a `range` function in OCaml or ReasonML and I don't want to write one, but I know [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) has one. Just write some JS,

```
// range.js
exports.range = require('ramda').range
```

Then wrap it with types, like

```
[@bs.module "./range.js"] external range' : (int,int) => array(int) = "range";
let range : (int,int) => list(int) = (a,b) => range'(a,b) |> Array.to_list
```

I'm not saying this is the ultimate way to use this tool, but I find it a very frictionless way to transition untyped garbage JS to something reasonably maintainable.

And you can leverage your existing JS library knowledge and keep building with reasonML, instead of spending your time writing a boring `range` function (which is also learning... of course)